# install virtualbox v4.3.x to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, 16.04

I have a vhdx file which is not read into virtulBox. I need to convert it to vdh format.

Normally, I could do it using the following command line :

```
VBoxManage clonehd --format VHD Laptop.VHDX Laptop.VHD
```

I have VB version 5 installed on my ubuntu 16.04 and **there is a regression issue** which does not allow me to convert the VDHX file to VDH ... see : https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14288

I'd like to downgrade to VB 4.3 but it seems there is no package for 16.04 Ubuntu version.

I'd appreciate some help regarding this issue.

Comment: they add a ppa here: http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2016/04/how-to-install-virtualbox-from-ppa-in.html

Comment: you can probably convert your image using `qemu-img` from `qemu-utils`:  `qemu-img convert -O vpc Laptop.VHDX Laptop.VHD`

Comment: @FrankSchrijver : instructions do not work. I've also read the following page : https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Older releases of Virtual Box are still available through downloading a DEB package from Oracle:

- [Download Virtual Box Old Builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds)

We can see that [for version 4.3.](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3) all sub-releases are still supported and available, including the extension files.

After downloading the appropriate Debian package we can install it by a double click with the Software Center or manually. Unfortunately with end of the release older versions of Virtual Box are not built for more recent releases of Ubuntu.

This may or may not lead to dependency issues that may easily be resolved or not.

Below example will install few dependencies and the binary for Virtual Box 4.3.38 in a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 :

1. Download and install a previous version of [`libvpx1`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libvpx1/download).

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libvpx1_1.3.0-2_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Install `libqt4`:

   ```
   sudo apt install libqt4-opengl
   ```
3. Download and install [Virtual Box](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.38/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.38-106717~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb):

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.3_4.3.38-106717-Ubuntu-raring_amd64.deb
   ```

If there are different, unresolvable dependency issues we may have to download the source code (also available from the page above) and build [Virtual Box from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file).

The Oracle repository is no longer maintained for older releases of Virtual Box.

Comment: runing old package form given page does not work. I'll consider compiling the source if I d'ont find any other solution. Thanks

Comment: It's two easy to resolve dependencies only, see edit. We can not however have it installed parallel to VB 5.0 (this may have to be removed temporarily until we had fixed our VHD file).